# I need a PrefixMap in python that is similar to the pygtrie.PrefixSet

Tags: python, trie

[pygtrie.PrefixSet](https://pygtrie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pygtrie.PrefixSet) works the like this:

```
ps = pygtrie.PrefixSet()
term = 'TERM'
ps.add(term)
term in ps
True
term + 'arbitrary postfix' in ps
True
```

What I need is map with similar logic. E.g.:

```
pm = PrefixMap()
pm[term] = 'Value'
pm[term + 'postfix']
'Value'
```

I am not sure if there is such a map in pygtrie or any library.

It would be also fine if there was an effective way to tell what was the original prefix added to the PrefixSet when the contains operator returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into the implementation of the PrefixSet and there is a Trie class that does the trick

```
In [32]: tr = pygtrie.Trie()
In [34]: term2
Out[34]: 'Some Term'
In [35]: term3 = term2+ 't'
In [36]: term3
Out[36]: 'Some Termt'
In [37]: tr[term2:] = 'VALUE'
In [48]: tr.shortest_prefix(term3)
Out[48]: (('S', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'r', 'm'): 'VALUE')
In [49]: tr.shortest_prefix(term3)[1]
Out[49]: 'VALUE'
```